# Download a dynamically created CSS file generated by Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, download, data-uri

I've searched through here countless times for help in my projects and now I've finally created an account. I was hoping to get some clarification on an answer I found to a similar question that had functionality similar to what I wanted. I essentially want the user to click a button and download a CSS file with data that was pushed to an empty array with JavaScript.

Here is the code I found that works to an extent (I have the function triggered on click within my actual code but this piece is the specific area I'm having troubles with.)

```
function download(filename, text) {
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

if (document.createEvent) {
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initEvent('click', true, true);
    pom.dispatchEvent(event);
}
else {
    pom.click();
}
}

download('responsive.css', 'Hello world!');
```

I've found that this works fine in Chrome, however when I had someone else test this in Firefox it was downloaded as responsive.css.txt . I did some research to see if it's possible to change "data:text/plain" to "data:text/css" in line 3 of my code but I was told by my tester that he was still having the same problem. In addition if anyone would have a solution for this to function in IE that would be great because right now when you click the button to download nothing happens.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to add the element to the DOM. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Answer (score 1):

if you set the type to download, it should work:

```
function download(filename, text) {
  var pom = document.createElement('a');
  pom.setAttribute(
    'href',
    'data:application/download;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text)
  );
  pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

  if (document.createEvent) {
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initEvent('click', true, true);
    pom.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
  else {
    pom.click();
  }
}

download('responsive.css', 'Hello world!');
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/s5on5dau/1/

Good luck ;)